# How to make proxy in API mule ESB

Tags: proxy, mule

I am newbie in mule esb. I want to trying make an API able to access another system with setting proxy in mule.

This is a program code that will hit to another system.

```
<until-successful synchronous="false"
                                failureExpression="#[header:INBOUND:http.status != 200]"
                                deadLetterQueue-ref="failedToCallback" maxRetries="${max.retries}"
                                secondsBetweenRetries="${second.between.retries}"
                                objectStore-ref="objectStore" doc:name="Until Successful">
                                <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                                method="GET"
                                        address="http://#[flowVars['urlcallback']]?id=#[flowVars['id']]"
                                contentType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP" />
                                </processor-chain>
                            </until-successful>
```

But using this code, i can't hit the url because timeout connection, so I need to use proxy.

Does anyone have any ideas where I should start to make proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Mulesoft [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/tutorials) contains tutorial for API proxy that you are trying to achieve.

MuleSoft has very comprehensive documentation. Go through [API Manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/), [deployment](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/tutorial-set-up-and-deploy-an-api-proxy) and [RAML](https://docs.mulesoft.com/getting-started/design-an-api) documentation. This will cover what you need.